# Line break at hyphen-initial words in dictionary

Tags: hyphenation

I am writing a double-columned dictionary using a quite complex style-file and an external input-file. However, in order to illustrate my problem, I simplified my template, yet incorporated my entire preamble (excluding the cmd for using my style-file of course).

My Problem: The dictionary contains hyphen-initial words, which are grammatical roots listed in the lexicon. This is probably relatively unusual. I already read about hyphenation problems with compound words containing hyphens; well, let me tell you hyphen-initial words are a pain in the neck:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} % sections are level 1
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=3cm, driver=dvips]{geometry}
%twocolumn, columnsep=25pt, 
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{45pt}
%\setlength{\columnseprule}{1.5pt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{dict}%use the style file

\newcommand*\justify{%
  \fontdimen2\font=0.4em% interword space
  \fontdimen3\font=0.2em% interword stretch
  \fontdimen4\font=0.1em% interword shrink
  \fontdimen7\font=0.1em% extra space
  \hyphenchar\font=`\-% allowing hyphenation
}

\usepackage{paralist}%for the \compactdesc environment
\usepackage{tgtermes}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{minipage}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Required for modifying headers and footers
\fancyhead[L]{{\rightmark}} % Top left header
\fancyhead[R]{{\leftmark}} % Top right header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt} % Rule under the header
\fancyfoot[C]{\vspace{2em}\textbf{{\thepage}}} % Bottom center footer
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.5pt} % Rule under the footer
\pagestyle{fancy} % Use the custom headers and footers throughout the document

\setdefaultleftmargin{1em}{}{}{}{}{}

%for illustrations
\usepackage{pstricks}
\psset{arrows=c-c}
\usepackage{overpic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newlength\cus
\sloppy

%for dotfills in the table of contents
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@section}
  {\hfil}
  {\leaders\hbox{\normalfont$\m@th\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep mu$}\hfill}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\HRule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}   % Horizontal rule definition

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum
\textbf{aham-turuk} umdrehen, umkehren, tauschen \texttt{ -teberuk, -toho, -teg, ahakey-toho, ahakey-roho, ahakey-moho-sumo, -uruk, -waruk, -teg, -toto, -tarum, -zug, -tuhouamanaratazam, -tuhouamanaratazamjoklimatahanan} 
\lipsum
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

As you can see in my example above, the hyphen-initial root forms (in `\texttt` -- which they HAVE to be in!) create some problems in terms of line breaking and word alignment. After reading about similar problems, I tried the `\justify` command, which produces another problem: The hyphens are separated from their host word, as you can see below:

```
    \documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} % sections are level 1
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=3cm, driver=dvips]{geometry}
%twocolumn, columnsep=25pt, 
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{45pt}
%\setlength{\columnseprule}{1.5pt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{dict}%use the style file

\newcommand*\justify{%
  \fontdimen2\font=0.4em% interword space
  \fontdimen3\font=0.2em% interword stretch
  \fontdimen4\font=0.1em% interword shrink
  \fontdimen7\font=0.1em% extra space
  \hyphenchar\font=`\-% allowing hyphenation
}

\usepackage{paralist}%for the \compactdesc environment
\usepackage{tgtermes}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{minipage}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Required for modifying headers and footers
\fancyhead[L]{{\rightmark}} % Top left header
\fancyhead[R]{{\leftmark}} % Top right header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt} % Rule under the header
\fancyfoot[C]{\vspace{2em}\textbf{{\thepage}}} % Bottom center footer
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.5pt} % Rule under the footer
\pagestyle{fancy} % Use the custom headers and footers throughout the document

\setdefaultleftmargin{1em}{}{}{}{}{}

%for illustrations
\usepackage{pstricks}
\psset{arrows=c-c}
\usepackage{overpic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newlength\cus
\sloppy

%for dotfills in the table of contents
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@section}
  {\hfil}
  {\leaders\hbox{\normalfont$\m@th\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep mu$}\hfill}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\HRule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}   % Horizontal rule definition

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum
\textbf{aham-turuk} umdrehen, umkehren, tauschen \texttt{\justify -teberuk, -toho, -teg, ahakey-toho, ahakey-roho, ahakey-moho-sumo, -uruk, -waruk, -teg, -toto, -tarum, -zug, -tuhouamanaratazam, -tuhouamanaratazamjoklimatahanan} 
\lipsum
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

I tried disabling **\hyphenchar\font=`-% allowing hyphenation** in the preamble, with the result that hyphen-internal words (like **ahakey-moho-sumo**) become unbreakable and produce overfull boxes.

Is there a way, to produce a text with the hyphen-initial forms in `\texttt` with correct spacing and attached hyphen? I tried toying around with the `extdash` package, but haven't had much luck.

Help me please!

Comment: You should be aware of the fact that assignments to `\fontdimen<number><font>` and `\hyphenchar<font>` are global.

Comment: "proper" spacing is essentially impossible as long as it's in "typewriter" mode.  is there any possibility of isolating each "word" with a separate `\command{...}` wrapper (keeping both commas and spaces out of the wrapper)?  if so, then i think the other problems are tractable.

Comment: There would be a way to apply a command to each word, however not without excluding the commas. I tried moving away from the typewriter-mode, yet the problem as displayed in ex. 2 above remains!

Comment: So, can anyone help me?

Comment: Anyone? Help, please!

Comment: @Lucas -- i tried a number of approaches before making a comment, and have this question flagged, but when i didn't get a notice that there was a following comment, i didn't come back to the question.  to alert someone who has commented that you have followed up, start your comment with @ followed by the name of the commenter, e.g. "@barbarabeeton".  in my experiments, i managed to get the initial hyphen to "stick", but then medial hyphens didn't break; i'll try again.

Comment: @barbarabeeton thx a lot for helping me. I asked the question again [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270106/prevent-line-break-of-dash-inital-words-hyphenation-problems](here) in order to get some attention. With the solution they gave me, I can glue the initial hyphen with \mbox, but constantly find cases where words exceed the columnwidth.